# bash date, create a new object on a specific timestamp that is n hours later from now

Tags: linux, bash, date

I am struggling to understand how to set a variable to be a particular timestamp.

given

```
dt=$(date);
```

dt which is the current date, say 2016-05-11 17:10:00, i want to create another date variable that is (roughly) 9 hours after dt, and on the exact hour, i.e., 2016-05-12 02:00:00.

In other words, I would set the new date to be 9 hours later, then set its minute and second to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-d` which lets you set a date, but also supports things like: `yesterday`, `5 hours ago` and `+5 hours`. Don't know the portability though.

And then format for your needs:

```
date -d '+9 hours' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I get this error (MAC OS 10.11.3): : usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: @zig Yea I though so.. It might just be GNU date that supports `+9 hours`. But can you try: `date -d '+9 hours'`

Comment: thanks, date -d '+9 hours'  produces the same error. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @zig Yes thats what I meant. Just trying to figure out if the format was the problem.

Comment: thanks, at least this works on our production server so i can still use it!